# CSS for setting SeparatorMenuItem color?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I would like to change the color of a [SeparatorMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SeparatorMenuItem.html) in my program. What CSS code will allow me to change its color?  I cannot find any information on it in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: Try `.menu .separator .line { -fx-background-color: foo; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered a number of times already for other controls. But here you go:

#### Follow the code

When you add a `SeparatorMenuItem`, you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/SeparatorMenuItem.java) or directly from your IDE.

```
public SeparatorMenuItem() {
    super(new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL), false);
    getStyleClass().add(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
}
```

It uses as `DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS`, `separator-menu-item`, and extends `CustomMenuItem`, which extends `MenuItem`, which *is not a control*, so this style class *might* not be the one we need to modify.

When you click the `Menu` node it displays a `ContextMenu` with style class `context-menu`, containing the menu items, the skin used to render the content is `ContextMenuSkin`, and each item uses a `ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer`:

> Container responsible for laying out a single row in the menu - in other words, this contains and lays out a single MenuItem, regardless of it's specific subtype.

The items are added to a `ContextMenuContent.MenuBox` (a VBox), but this container doesn't have a specific style class.

The content node of the `SeparatorMenuItem` is a `Separator`, a Node with style class `separator`, that has `SeparatorSkin` as skin, and it just renders a `line`, a region with `line` as style class.

Finally, we can do something like this to change the `SeparatorMenuItem` color:

```
.context-menu > * > .separator > .line {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}
```

[image: Separator Menu Item]

As you can see, the main issue is finding out the real node that is being rendered in the scene-graph, along with their parents.

It is also helpful to print this:

```
menu.setOnShown(e -> {
        Node node = separatorMenuItem.getContent();
        do {
            System.out.println("Node: " + node);
            node = node.getParent();
        } while (node != null);
    });
```

It will print something like:

```
Node: Separator@296d4a5a[styleClass=separator]
Node: ContextMenuContent$MenuBox@14793a99
Node: ContextMenuContent[id=null, styleClass=context-menu]
Node: PopupControl$CSSBridge[id=null, styleClass=context-menu]
Node: Pane@2decd2c5[styleClass=root popup]
```

#### Use ScenicView

Download the JDK 11 version for your platform from [here](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view), and while running your app, launch it from `scenicview/bin/scenicview`:

[image]

While you will see the full scenegraph hierarchy when you display the menu content, like in the picture above, in this case there is a major issue that prevents you from click on any of the nodes to inspect its content and style classes, without closing the menu.

So while it won't help in this case, it is always a really useful tool to use.

#### Check modena.css

Modena is the theme applied by default to all the built-in JavaFX controls.

Either [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), or from your IDE, you can find the exact style applied to the control.

In this case:

```
.context-menu .separator:horizontal .line {
    -fx-border-color: -fx-box-border transparent transparent transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 1 0 0 0;
}
```

So now you can change that as needed. Note that it matches precisely what we have found via source code.